# fluentd out_forward delay to send the log events

Tags: fluentd, forward

I setup one fluentd-daemonset in k8s to read pod logs running with root user, then forward logs to another fluentd pod. The log can be sent to fluentd pod, but it always delay about 64 seconds. I checked docs in fluentd website:
https://docs.fluentd.org/output/forward
but it does not mention anything about delay or buffer sending logs. Is there anyone having the same issue? Thanks.

```
<label @fileOutput>
  <match *.**>
    @type forward
    log_level debug
    send_timeout 60s
    recover_wait 10s
    hard_timeout 60s
    keepalive true
    compress gzip
    <server>
      name fluentd
      host fluentd
      port 24224
      weight 100
    </server>
  </match>
</label>
```

Comment: Please take a look at the default flushing parameters: https://docs.fluentd.org/configuration/buffer-section#flushing-parameters.

Comment: Not sure about your requirements; but for starters, you can test with `flush_mode immediate`.

Comment: @Azeem, as my understanding buffer is for fluentd to save the events to memory or disk before sending it. For example, if server connection lost for a second then during that short period fluentd can store the events somewhere and send it when server connection restored. But here I didn't use <buffer> here, I guess it just send  with out_forward plugin

Comment: Right. So, did you try and test by configuring the `<buffer>` section to validate this understanding?

Comment: @Azeem, yes flush_mode immediate works. Thank you so much for providing this tips.

Comment: Glad to hear that! No problem.